# Slow download speed in Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, speed-test

I am making speedtest application with Flutter. I tried dio and http libraries. While I get full speed on iOS, I get at least 35% - 50% lower values on Android. I tried many ways, I read articles for hours, but I couldn't find a solution. I made a connection with Kotlin and increased Byte etc., again low speed. The upload speed seems very high to low. That's a problem too

Comment: Hello
Were you able to find a solution? I'm facing the same issue for the past few days.

Comment: @Danny i'm using dio.get with ResponseType.stream. I think this is best setting